# Identifying the name of the clicked shape from another sheet

Tags: excel, shapes, vba

I work on sheet 1 and sheet 2 and in both sheets there are shapes that contain code. The Shape ID in sheet 1 is "RUN 1" and in sheet 2 is "EQ-1". I already have a code that can identify the shape ID I've clicked on sheet1 / sheet2. But the code is debug with the explanation "the item with the specified name wasn't found". Thanks. Please help :)
***This code must be located in the sheet 2***

```
sub x ()

'the first trial
If Sheet1.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name = "RUN 1" Then Sheet2.Cells(1, 2) = "x"
If activesheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name = "EQ-1" Then Sheet2.Cells(1, 2) = "x"

'the second trial
If Sheet1.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name = "RUN 1" Or _
activesheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name = "EQ-1" Then Sheet2.Cells(1, 2) = "x"

end sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try...

```
Sub x()

    If Application.Caller = "RUN 1" Or Application.Caller = "EQ-1" Then
        Sheet2.Cells(1, 2) = "x"
    End If

End Sub
```

Hope this helps!